# Can I copy row from one Google Spreadsheet to another based on certain criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet to track student loan outs:

> Column `A` is the student name
>   Column `B` is how many loan outs they have received
>   Column `C` is the class period Column `D` is the teacher name
>   Column `E` is the type of loan out received
>   Column `F` is the date received 
>   Column `G` is loan out returned.

Columns `E`,`F`,`G` repeat in each row 5 more times.
Column `B` has a Counta formula count of each time a loan out is given to that student.

I would like each teacher to have a sheet within that book that lists the students that have 2 or more loan outs instead of having to look at the master list.

So for example, as a teacher I would have a seperate sheet to look at and when a student of mine gets two or more loan outs it would copy that row into my seperate spreadsheet.

So I am looking for a formula or script that would first look in column `B` for a number greater than `1` and then by teacher name in column `D` and pull the data to the seperate sheet. I would do this for each teacher.

I already have a script running that automatically adds the date when a loan out is entered.  I don't know if this possible too. Here is a link to a blank sheet than I am using: [Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgNLZnbpF6YqdHM0ai0zUlE0RmFBdWdjT2ozYXpIU0E&usp=sharing)

Comment: The link you provided is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. sheetSpider does not appear to be available anymore. I tried writing my own script and it kinda worked but it was slow and didn't update reliably when the source data changed.

I eventually solved my problem with a pivot table (Data->Pivot table report...). Just select the range, then add all the columns you want to see as Rows (sounds counterintuitive I know) and set Filters for Column B > 1 and Column D = teacher's name. Create a new pivot table for each teacher on its own sheet where the second filter varies. More details about pivot tables in Google Sheets [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272914?hl=en&ref_topic=1258755). For me it is quick and updates well whenever the source data changes.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [sheetSpider](https://sites.google.com/site/heroscripts/course-feedback/sheetspider) from the script gallery. (Tools > Script gallery)

It's built for situations like the one you have presented.

Comment: The script gallery is not available anymore.